# why does search for rome, italy return 4 duplicate results?

Tags: arcgis

My request to geocode Rome, Italy, returns this:

```
{"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326},"locations":[
    {"name":"Roma, Latium, Italy", "extent":{"xmin":12.389896,"ymin":41.800739,"xmax":12.577896,"ymax":41.988739},"feature":{"geometry":{"x":12.483895995000069,"y":41.894738560000064}, "attributes":{"Type":"National Capital","Match_addr":"Roma, Latium, Italy","Addr_type":"POI"}}},
    {"name":"Roma, Latium, Italy", "extent":{"xmin":12.389896,"ymin":41.800739,"xmax":12.577896,"ymax":41.988739},"feature":{"geometry":{"x":12.483895995000069,"y":41.894738560000064}, "attributes":{"Type":"National Capital","Match_addr":"Roma, Latium, Italy","Addr_type":"POI"}}},
    {"name":"Roma, Latium, Italy", "extent":{"xmin":12.389896,"ymin":41.800739,"xmax":12.577896,"ymax":41.988739},"feature":{"geometry":{"x":12.483895995000069,"y":41.894738560000064}, "attributes":{"Type":"National Capital","Match_addr":"Roma, Latium, Italy","Addr_type":"POI"}}},
    {"name":"Roma, Latium, Italy", "extent":{"xmin":12.389896,"ymin":41.800739,"xmax":12.577896,"ymax":41.988739},"feature":{"geometry":{"x":12.483895995000069,"y":41.894738560000064}, "attributes":{"Type":"National Capital","Match_addr":"Roma, Latium, Italy","Addr_type":"POI"}}}
]}
```

Here is the [request URL](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=rome%2Citaly&category=Populated%20Place&outFields=Type%2CMatch_addr%2CAddr_type&f=json&maxLocations=10).

The entries all appear to be duplicates. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: My eyes. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: @erip: I submitted an edit for the formatting. I did it in a way that illustrates the issue better than the OP but also better than a full pretty-print would do.

Comment: Just a guess here but I'd guess it is probably for drawing a polygon on a map, but since you are asking for a specific location it is returning the same object in locations.

Comment: this is the request (i'm sorry, i don't see anything about formatting on this page): http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=rome%2Citaly&category=Populated%20Place&outFields=Type%2CMatch_addr%2CAddr_type&f=json&maxLocations=10

Comment: I'm not sure why these duplicates are shown, but my best guess would be that there are several points with Rome in Italy at the exact same spot registered on the service. If you wish to only have 1 result you can use this url: [ArcGIS Geocode With 1 result bases on score](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=rome&maxLocations=1&f=pjson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The reason is alternate names for the same place.

If you modify your request to [return all fields](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=rome%2Citaly&category=Populated%20Place&outFields=*&f=json&maxLocations=10), you will find that the following fields are different across the four results:

- Score
- Rank
- City

The key difference is the City value. It's giving you four different spellings for Rome (Roma, Rome, Roeme, and Rom). The reason is so that the place can be found when searching for any of its various spellings.

You're most likely to see multiple results when searching for global cities, like Rome or New York (a.k.a. Nova York, Nova Iorque, etc.), since they are the ones that tend to have names in multiple languages.

As one of the comments suggests, you can work around this behavior by setting `maxLocations` to 1. The results are sorted by rank, so you'll get likely the best result at the top of the list.

Comment: will go with more fields and maybe add some back end processing. limiting reply to 1 is too optimistic for me.  i appreciate both suggestions.